# GridView to rename file name

Tags: android

I use below code to show photo in GridView:

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};  
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID); 
int count = cursor.getCount();
int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
int image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
fd.clearPhonePhoto();
int i;
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
cursor.moveToPosition(i);
int id = cursor.getInt(image_column_index);
String p = cursor.getString(image_path_index);
Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
FilePath.add(p);  
FileThumb.add(b); 
}

b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_4);
b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
int i;
for(i = 0; i < Check.length; i++) {
if(Check[i]) {
AlertDialog.Builder renameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhonePhotoListActivity.this);
renameDialog.setTitle("Rename");
final EditText name = new EditText(AActivity.this);
name.setText(FilePath.get(i).substring(FilePath.get(i).lastIndexOf("/") + 1));   //set old file name
renameDialog.setView(name);
final String oripath = FilePath.get(i);
renameDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
rename(oripath, name.getText().toString());
Intent it = new Intent(AActivity.this, AActivity.class);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


startActivity(it); 
}
});
renameDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
});
renameDialog.show();
}
}
}
});
gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.phone_photo);
AAdapter = new AAdapter(this, FilePath, FileThumb);
gv.setAdapter(AAdapter);
```

Above in onCreate().
rename() method as below:

```
public void rename(String ori, String edit) {
File rename = new File(ori);
String newpath = ori.substring(0, ori.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + edit;
rename.renameTo(new File(newpath));
}
```

In first time, the dialog show the correct file name and rename the file name success.
But second time, the dialog show the old file name which is not renamed, and rename failed.
How to modify to avoid it?

I try to restart the app, it still show the old file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only modify the file name, **but did't modify the file name in the database**, you need refresh the database to ensure the rename.

you can try this to fresh the database:

```
    Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())));
    context.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
```

will mount the storage, and scan the media.

Comment: when you finish the rename operate, you can refresh, but when refresh, you need read new database data.

Comment: How to read new database data? I try add in onCreate top. But after rename it not refresh. But if stop activity and restart activity. it refresh.

Comment: But after rename, I use new intent restart activity.

Comment: onCreate will invoke once except stop activity and restart it.  read new database data is your first paste code:`String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};...`  .  whatever you choose to start a new activity or not, you need refresh the data and before show new data.

Comment: But 'Intent it = new Intent(AActivity.this, AActivity.class);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(it);' has already run the line 'String[] projection = ...' in onCreate again. Is it not refresh?

Comment: after the rename or before the AActivity.class show data, you need use my suggestion code to refresh, are you ?

Comment: I add on the top of onCreate(). After rename, I start new intent to start a new AActivity, and has run the line 'String[] projection = ...'. But it seems not refresh. But if I stop the app and restart it, it refresh.

Comment: context.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
 The context I did not use. "context cannot be resolved"

Comment: sendBroadcast is method of the context, so you can invoke in the activity use `sendBroadcast(scanIntent)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to re-Draw your Grid View method by getting the data from database and call it after renaming and update in DB.

Edit:

```
onCreate(){  
...............  
............  
drawGrid();  
}


public void getData(){  
File.clear();  
Path.clear();    
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,              MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};  
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);   
int count = cursor.getCount();  
int image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);  
int image_path_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);  
fd.clearPhonePhoto();  
int i;  
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {  
cursor.moveToPosition(i);  
int id = cursor.getInt(image_column_index);  
String p = cursor.getString(image_path_index);  
Bitmap b =   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,   MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);  
FilePath.add(p);    
FileThumb.add(b);   
}}

public void drawGrid(){  
getData();  
gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.phone_photo);  
AAdapter = new AAdapter(this, FilePath, FileThumb);  
gv.setAdapter(AAdapter);  
}
```

call onDraw() on click of AlertDialog "OK"
and I think it works..

Comment: when you rename your files it will suceccfully renamed. am i right if yes then you need to redraw your GridView By latest data getting after rename.Do one thing make a separate method of getting data from DB first you call it onCreate() method then after renaming dialog "OK" click and then make your GridView again. Hope this will helpfull to you

Comment: How to redraw your GridView By latest data getting after rename?